# How to correctly use COUNT() when multiple joins are used?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following schema:
[image]

Multiple `webinar` entities can have multiple `categories` hence the `webinarcategorymapping` table.

What I need to achieve is find the most popular `webinars` (by likes number) of a specific `category`.

For doing this, I've written the query below:

```sql
select
    webinar.id, webinar.name as "webinar", webinar.publishat,
    string_agg(category.name, ',' order by category.name) as categories,
    count("like".likeableid) as "likes_count"
    from
        webinar
        join "like" on webinar.id = "like".likeableid and "like".likeabletype = 'webinar'
        join webinarcategorymapping on webinarcategorymapping.webinarid = webinar.id
        join category on category.id = webinarcategorymapping.categoryid
    group by "like".likeableid, webinar.id
    having
        string_agg(category.name, ',' order by category.name) ilike '%CategoryName%'
        and count("like".likeableid) > 0
    order by count("like".likeableid) desc;
```

Due to the many-to-many relationship between `category` and `webinar` I've decided to join all categories for every `webinar` into a comma-separated value by using `string_agg`. This way I'll be able to perform the search by category by using `ilike %search_term%`.

In the `like` table the `likeabletype` must be equal to `webinar` and the `likeableid` filed is the id of an entity on which the like is made. So, in my case, when querying the `like` table I need to use `likeabletype='webinar'` and `likeableid = webinar.id` conditions.

The problem is that is gives me incorrect `likes_count` results (I guess it's due to multiple joins that duplicate many rows).

However using `count(distinct "like".likeableid)` doesn't help as it just gives me `1` for every row.

---

What should I change in my query in order to get correct result from `count()` of `likes`?

Comment: You can GROUP BY in subqueries, before joining.

Comment: It is not clear how `like`s are connected to the other tables.  Also, what specific category do you care about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I need to achieve is find the most popular webinars (by likes number) of a specific category.

You can aggregate the `like`s in a subquery and just filter on the categories:

```
select w.id, w.name as "webinar", w.publishat, num_likes
from webinar w join
     (select l.likableid, count(*) as num_likes
      from "like" l
      where l.likeabletype = 'webinar'
      group by l.likeableid
     ) l
     on w.id = l.likeableid join
     webinarcategorymapping wcm
     on wcm.webinarid = w.id join
     category c
     on c.id = wcm.categoryid
where c.name = ?
order by num_likes desc;
```

Comment: Your query works correctly, but gives me duplicate rows. If I add `distinct` after the first `select`, it all works as it should. Is using `distinct` the right way to achieve the needed result here?

Comment: @DenisYakovenko . . . I suspect the duplicate rows are caused by multiple categories matching the webinar.  You can instead replace the category comparison using `where exists` with a correlated subquery.